# How do I get my Bump Reminder Event working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This Issue Has Been Resolved. I actually did figure it out...it was mainly an issue of Not Explaining the Question Right, which is completely my fault. I should have explained that i want my bot to listen for when someone sends /bump to DISBOARD, looking at my question, it looks like i was asking as to why when i send /bump to my bot, it doesnt work, which is not what i wanted the outcome to be. It was as simple as inserting `if (message.interaction && message.interaction.commandName === "page" && message.author.id === "302050872383242240") {` in there. Thank you all for your help

So, I have been working on a new discord bot for the past month or so. I went on to making a Bump Reminder that will send a message saying Thanks for bumping when the bump is successful, and then 2 hours later, ping the Bump Reminder Role.

Here is the issue though. Idk if its because of how its written or such, but whenever i do /bump, and its successful, i dont get a reaction in the channel where the /bump was sent, or anything in the console

```
const config = require('../../config/config');
console.log('Bump Reminder Loaded!!');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (client, interaction) => {
  try {
    const roleId = config.plugins.bumpreminder.roleID;
    console.log('Role ID:', roleId);
    const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId);
    console.log('Role:', role);
    const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.plugins.bumpreminder.channelID);
    console.log('Channel:', channel);

    if (!role) {
      console.log(`Error: Could not find role with ID ${roleId} in server ${interaction.guild.name}.`);
      return;
    }

    if (interaction.commandName === "bump" && interaction.user.id === "302050872383242240") {
      const reminderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Thank You For Bumping!!')
        .setDescription(`Please Check Back in 2 Hours!!`)
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTimestamp();

      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [reminderEmbed] });
      setTimeout(() => {
        channel.send(`<@&${roleId}> Don't forget to bump the server to get more members!`);
      }, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I am using Discord.js v13, so idk if its because Interactions arent supported in v13, but i was told they were supported.

I was told that creating an interactionCreate Event would help, so i did that,

```
const eventName = 'interactionCreate';

module.exports = async (Discord, client, interaction) => {
  const config = require('../../config/config');
  const bumpReminder = require('./bumpreminder.js');
  try {
    bumpReminder(Discord, client, interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work...Maybe i did something wrong with my interactionCreate event.

Also, here is the event handler, that registers the event files:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = require('../index');

console.log(`Event Handler Started at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`);

module.exports = (Discord, client) => {
  try {
    const load_dir = (dir) => {
      const event_files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

      for (const file of event_files) {
        const event = require(`../events/${file}`);
        let event_name;
        if (file === 'message.js') {
            event_name = 'messageCreate';
        } else if (file === 'guildCreate.js') {
            event_name = 'guildCreate';
        } else if (file === 'autorole.js') {
            event_name = 'guildMemberUpdate';
        } else if (file === 'greeter.js') {
            event_name = 'guildMemberAdd';
        } else if (file === 'leaver.js') {
            event_name = 'guildMemberRemove';
        } else if (file === 'ghostping.js') {
            event_name = 'messageDelete';
        } else if (file === 'interactions.js') {
            event_name = 'interactionCreate';
        } else {
          event_name = event.eventName || file.split('.')[0];
        }
        client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
      }
    }

    load_dir('events');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: If you're using slash commands then there won't be a message object. Please share the code that's calling this function because something's not right.

Comment: Here it is: https://sourceb.in/Db0SeyVy6p

Comment: That looks like a `messageCreate` event handler. You need to be listening to `interactionCreate` for slash commands.

Comment: Would i just copy the code from messageCreate to interactionCreate, but only copy the bump reminder function instead of all the functions?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html

Comment: Alright, i can see what i should do. Thanks

Comment: Alright, so even after all that, it still does not work

Comment: Please edit your post with the appropriate details

Comment: Finished Editing

Comment: Can you add the code that actually registers the event listener

Comment: Just added the Event Class Code

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have the wrong Discord User ID for yourself?

You have 302050872383242240 in your code, but that leads to a user called "DISBOARD#2760" which I believe to be a bot of the https://disboard.org/ website. I would double check your Discord ID to ensure that you have the correct one.

You can also check this theory by adding an ELSE statement under your IF statement to see if it is failing because of this IF statement.

Also, it is bad coding practice to have both of those IF statements combined into one like that, because if either of them fail, then they will both hit the same ELSE (or as you have it now, they do nothing).

I'd recommend splitting the IF statements up and giving some sort of error message to the user like this if the user ID statement fails:

```
interaction.reply({content: `:exclamation: You don't have permission to use this command.`, ephemeral: true});
```

And maybe a console log with a message if the IF statment fails:

```
console.log(`Unrecognized command used`);
```

Comment: I actually did figure it out...it was mainly an issue of Not Explaining the Question Right, which is completely my fault. I should have explained that i want my bot to listen for when someone sends /bump to DISBOARD, looking at my question, it looks like i was asking as to why when i send /bump to my bot, it doesnt work, which is not what i wanted the outcome to be. It was as simple as inserting if (message.interaction && message.interaction.commandName === "page" && message.author.id === "302050872383242240") { in there.